# How to get closest form element of parent class. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, pug

I am trying to add vote up buttons to my blog comments. I am looping through each comment like this:

```
.row
    for comment in Comments
        .row
            p #{comment}
            .votecell(style='width:30px;float:left;margin-left: 15px;')
                .voteUp(id='#{comment.id}', style='margin-bottom: -17px;') &#9650;
                            form.form-horizontal(id='voteUp', enctype="multipart/form-data", method='POST')
                                input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf)
                                input(type='hidden', name='commentID', value='#{comment.id}')
                                <br>
```

Then using jQuery I am trying to submit the form that is a child of the button that was clicked.

```
$(".voteUp").click(function () {
    var form = $(this).closest(".form-horizontal")
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/voteUp', //the URL to your node.js server that has data
            type: 'POST',
            data:  form.serialize()
        }).done(function(data){

        }); 
    });
});
```

The problem is it always submits the form from the first comment on the page no matter which voteUp button is clicked. I know this is because in jQuery $(this) == this[0], but I am unsure what other options are available to reference the clicked object. Anyone know how I can grab the child form of the clicked button?

Here is what the html output looks like:

```
<div id="5463ce6bd6e5e5d403e80b3f" style="margin-bottom: -17px;" class="voteUp">
    ▲
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="4JbLbnEcRvq7ZuAhpZCXavMq7JW/vnIZlxW/o=">
        <input type="hidden" name="commentID" value="5463ce6bd6e5e5d403e80b3f">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is that weird notation?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a generated block of the HTML

Comment: please show sample output html rather than server code. It doesn't appear that `voteUp` is inside the form to begin with

Comment: Its jade. http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: It looks like you're giving every form the same "id" value, which can cause problems.

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question to include the html output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using children instead of closest. http://jsfiddle.net/hLraqdq1/

```
$(".voteUp").click(function () {
    var form = $(this).children(".form-horizontal");
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/voteUp', //the URL to your node.js server that has data
            type: 'POST',
            data:  form.serialize()
        }).done(function(data){

        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: .children() doesn't seem to find any form and submits the ajax call with no data.

Comment: Could you paste some generated HTML in here ? It would make it easier to debug your script ! Thanks.

Comment: Well, it looks like there is no form with class "form-horizontal" !

Comment: Sorry was trying a few changes. Changed back now to the original output.

Comment: Here is an updated JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hLraqdq1/3/ everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the **.next()** method.

```
$('.voteUp').next('.form-horizontal')
```

That would select the next element with the form-horizontal class and only that.

Here's the documentation - see if it's what you need. http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Tried using .next() and it returns the form for the first comment on the page. Hitting any .voteUp button always submits the form for the first comment. I think the problem is with $(this) always being a reference to the first div with that class name.

Comment: `next()` looks for sibling, the form is a descendant not a sibling

Answer (score 2):

So the main issue is you are traversing in the wrong direction within the DOM tree.

`closest()` starts with current selector and looks up the tree for ancestors but you are wanting to look for descendents.

Just use `find()` instead of `closest()`

References:

**[closest() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

**[find() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**